# 2-D array in C, address generation

Tags: c, arrays

How do addresses get generated in arrays in C, say how does a [x][y] get to a particular value, i know its not that big a question but just about to actually start coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it is done depending on your data type of whose array you have considered.

Say for an Integer array, each value holds 4 bytes, thus a row X long will take 4X bytes.

Thus a 2-D matrix of X*Y will be of 4*X*Y Bytes.

> Any address say Arry[X][Y] would be
>   calculated as : (Base Address of Arry)
>   + (X * No. of columns) + ( Y // Offset in current row )

Answer (score 1):

2-dimensional arrays in C are rectangular. For example:

```
int matrix[2][3];
```

allocates a single block of memory `2*3*sizeof(int)` bytes in size. Addressing `matrix[0][1]` is just a matter of adding `0 * (3 * sizeof(int))` to `sizeof(int)`. Then add that sum to the address at which `matrix` starts.

Answer (score 0):

A nested array is an array of arrays.

For example, an `int[][6]` is an array of `int[6]`.
Assuming a 4-byte `int`, each element in the outer array is `6 * 4` = 24 bytes wide.

Therefore, `arr[4]` gets the third array in the outer array, or `*(arr + 4 * 24)`.

`arr[4]` is a normal `int[]`.  `arr[4][2]` gets the second `int` in this inner array, or `*(arr + 4 * 24 + 2 * 4)`

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
char anArray[][13]={"Hello World!","February","John"};
```

You can visualize it as:

`anArray`:

```
H|e|l|l|o| |W|o|r|l|d|!|\0|F|e|b|r|u|a|r|y|\0|\0|\0|\0|\0|J|o|h|n|\0|\0|\0|0|\0
^                          ^                              ^
0                          13                             26
```

Comment: Actually, all characters for which you don't give an initializer are guaranteed to be initialized to \0. So you should replace all your `+` by `\0`.